# $http request wrapped in Service returns the whole response in resolve state Provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state defined like this:

```
.state('list', {
            url: '/list',
            controller: 'ctrl',
            resolve: {
                data: ['DataService', function(DataService) {                                 
                    return DataService.getList();
                    }]
            }
        })
```

The getList of DataService makes the http request:

```
    var httpRequest = $http(categoryRequest);
        httpRequest.then(function (response) {
                 return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log('could not get categories from server');
            });

        return httpRequest;
```

In controller I just assign the list to its list property:

```
function ctrl(data) {
    this.list = data.data;
}
```

The problem:

No matter what I return in success callback of http request, I always get the whole response in resolve of state provider.

So I have to do **data.data** in controller to get the data from response.

Questions:

1. Is my assumption true that I will always get the whole reponse in resolve?
2. How to get just the data form response that I do not have to get it in controller.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
var httpRequest = $http(categoryRequest);
```

So httpRequest is a `Promise<Response>`

```
httpRequest.then(function (response) {
```

This creates another promise, but this new promise is not assigned to anything.

```
return httpRequest;
```

This returns the original `Promise<Response>`.

You want

```
httpRequest = httpRequest.then(function (response) {
```

Or simply

```
return httpRequest.then(function (response) {
```

So that what you return is the new promise.

To give you a simpler analog example, your code is similar to

```
var a = 1;
a + 1;
return a;
```

That returns 1, not 2.

To return 2, you need

```
var a = 1;
a = a + 1; 
return a;
```

or

```
var a = 1;
return a + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First, the service is returning the original httpPromise and not the promise derived from the original promise. Second, the error handler is **converting** the rejection to a success.

```
var httpRequest = $http(categoryRequest);
    //httpRequest.then(function (response) {
var derivedPromise = httpRequest.then(function onSuccess(response) {
    //return to chain data
    return response.data;
}).catch(function onReject(error) {
    console.log('could not get categories from server');
    //IMPORTANT to avoid conversion
    throw error;
    //OR
    //return $q.reject(error);
});

//return httpRequest;
return derivedPromise;
```

The `.then` method of a promise returns a new promise derived from the original promise. It does not mutate the original promise.

A common problem is the **omission** of a `throw` or `return $q.reject` statement from a rejection handler. Functions without such statements return a value of `undefined` which will **convert** a rejection to a success which resolves as `undefined`.